# Yarn can not install package

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I have an error while I am trying install Axios package...please help me

> error An unexpected error occurred: "http://registry.npmjs.org/axios: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000".*

Comment: Can you please show **yarn-error.log**?